# Adding SEO tags for each page in Yii2

Tags: html, yii2, phpunit, metadata, meta-tags

I’m very new to this topic. I’ve a site written with PHP in Yii framework. In my customize CDN, where I inject my content through it, my developer designed a section that I can assign different Meta tags or SEO tags to various pages. My issue is that that mechanism does not work and, in fact, when I put, say Meta description, it appears to all pages same. I can’t access to my developer to correct this issue. In below, I’ve provided the codes for layout and Metadata.php.
As I mentioned, I’m new to this topic and don’t know which codes I should submit for considering. If more codes are needed, please ask me.

My goal is to correct my backend entry (Metadata list section) such that each page has unique Meta tags provided by me.

```
$metadata = \common\models\base\Metadata::find()->where(['page_routing' => 
Yii::$app->controller->id."/". Yii::$app->controller->action->id ])->one();
if ( empty($metadata ) )
$metadata = \common\models\base\Metadata::find()->where(['id' => 1 ])- 
>one();
?>

<?php $this->beginPage() ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">

<head>
<meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
<?php echo Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="robots" content="<?=$metadata->meta_robots?>"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://physexams.com/<?=Yii::$app->controller- 
>id."/". Yii::$app->controller->action->id?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=$metadata->og_image?>"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$metadata->og_title?>â€Œ"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=$metadata->og_description?>"/>
<meta name="twitter:image" content="<?=$metadata->twitter_image?>"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_CA" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="index" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="1 Days" />
<meta name="doc-class" content="Living Document" />
<meta name="language" content="english">
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
<link rel="publisher" href="<?=$metadata->publisher?>" />
<title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>

<?php $this->head() ?>
```

In above, for being short, I cut other unneeded meta tags and submitted part of the code. If the whole code is necessary, I could submit it. 
AND the Codes for Metadata.php

```
namespace common\models\base;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the base-model class for table "metadata".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $page_routing
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $meta_description
 * @property string $author
 * @property string $author_link
 * @property string $publisher
 * @property string $og_title
 * @property string $og_type
 * @property string $og_image
 * @property string $og_url
 * @property string $og_description
 * @property string $twitter_card
 * @property string $twitter_url
 * @property string $twitter_title
 * @property string $twitter_description
 * @property string $twitter_image
 * @property string $meta_keywords
 * @property string $meta_robots
 * @property string $meta_copyright
 * @property string $itemprop
 * @property string $Search_Display
 */
 class Metadata extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
 {



/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'metadata';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['meta_description', 'meta_keywords', 'Search_Display'], 
'string'],
        [['page_routing', 'title', 'author', 'author_link', 'publisher', 
'og_title', 'og_type', 'og_image', 'og_url', 'og_description', 
'twitter_url', 'twitter_title', 'twitter_description', 'twitter_image', 
'meta_robots', 'meta_copyright'], 'string', 'max' => 1000],
        [['twitter_card'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['itemprop'], 'string', 'max' => 2000]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'page_routing' => 'Page Routing',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'meta_description' => 'Meta Description',
        'author' => 'Author',
        'author_link' => 'Author Link',
        'publisher' => 'Publisher',
        'og_title' => 'Og Title',
        'og_type' => 'Og Type',
        'og_image' => 'Og Image',
        'og_url' => 'Og Url',
        'og_description' => 'Og Description',
        'twitter_card' => 'Twitter Card',
        'twitter_url' => 'Twitter Url',
        'twitter_title' => 'Twitter Title',
        'twitter_description' => 'Twitter Description',
        'twitter_image' => 'Twitter Image',
        'meta_keywords' => 'Meta Keywords',
        'meta_robots' => 'Meta Robots',
        'meta_copyright' => 'Meta Copyright',
        'itemprop' => 'Itemprop',
        'Search_Display' => 'Search  Display',
    ];
}
}
```

The Codes for Main.php of config:

```
return [
'id' => 'app-frontend',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log', 'thumbnail'],
'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
//'defaultRoute' => '/site/index',

'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',

        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'home' => 'site/index' ,
            '/' => 'site/index', 
            'frontend/web' => 'site/index',
            'index' => 'site/index',
            'site' => 'site/index',
            'site/login' => 'site/login' ,
            'site/contact' => 'site/contact' ,
            'site/about' => 'site/about' ,
            'site/faq' => 'site/faq' ,
            'profile/logout' => 'profile/logout',
            'profile' => 'profile/index',
            'lesson/<lesson:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'courses/internal',
            'lesson' => 'courses/internal',

            'course/<cat:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'courses/index',
            'courses' => 'courses/index',

            'exam/<cat:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'exam/internal',
            'exam' => 'exam/index',

            'ticket' => 'ticket/index',



            'flashcard/<cat:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'blog/internal',
            'blog/<cat:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'blog/cat',
            'blog' => 'blog/index',

            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 
'<controller>/<action>',


        ],
        ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],

    'thumbnail' => [
        'class' => 'himiklab\thumbnail\EasyThumbnail',
        'cacheAlias' => 'assets/gallery_thumbnails',
    ],
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
        'bundles' => [
                    'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                        'js' => [
                            'jquery.min.js'
                        ]
                    ],

                    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                        'css' => [
                           'css/bootstrap.min.css',
                        ]
                    ],

        ],
    ],
],
'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: It should have been a widget which should assign the meta tags for every page rather than adding a query inside the layout file, secondly your metadata tags seem to be stored against the page URL for example if you are on the home page your URL is `http://example.com/site/index` then it searches for the meta tags in the `MetaData` model by comparing the column `page_routing`.

Comment: so your URLs stored in the table should be like `site/index` for displaying the `index` specific `metadata` tags from the db and if it does not find any metadata tags saved against the url `site/index` then it searches the metadata with `id=1` , so if you are getting the same metadata tags on all pages , check first if you have the SEO friendly URLs stored in the database and you have enabled the `UrlManager` option `enablePrettyUrl`, better to add some rows from the database for any specific page

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks for your reply. I added the relevant code. This shows that my URLs are SEO-friendly. Now, what do I do?

Comment: okay can you show some metadata rows for any page saved in the database, or if you dont want to share add the data here you can confirm by checking the column `page_routing` in the database if it saves the url in the format `controller/action`. Moreover the condition in the layout file should be `if ($metadata)` rather than `if ( empty($metadata ) )` as the `ActiveQueryInterface` method [`one()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#one()-detail) returns an array if result found or boolean `false` if no results.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Where can I find your request about " showing some metadata rows"? Is there in a specific file or directory? Can you explain more about your request?

Comment: i am talking about the metadata that you are saving from the backend in the database table, which are further pulled by using the query `$metadata = \common\models\base\Metadata::find()->where(['page_routing' => 
Yii::$app->controller->id."/". Yii::$app->controller->action->id ])->one();` just confirm that you are saving the `page_routing` column in the same format `site/index` as you are comparing in the query using `Yii::$app->controller->id."/". Yii::$app->controller->action->id`, you need to look into the database table  `metadata`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I provided a screenshot of metadata database in below link "https://screenshot.net/y3wj6sp"

Comment: okay, change the condition as itold in my previous comment, change `if ( empty($metadata ) )` to `if ($metadata)` and then got to the `Faq` page on your site and verify if the metadata tags are displayed correctly, also is there only a single layout file used overall on the site or there are other than the one added in your question

Comment: The very first entry in your table is `site` if this entry is for the main home page it should be saved like `site/index`.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I do your request but, the site is down, you can go and see the error. In addition, I have a single layout file.

Comment: ok add the url for your site

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam https://physexams.com

Comment: add `var_dump($metadata);exit;` on top after the query in the layout page, and tell me i will refresh the page again

Comment: okay, i saw that change you did as i asked, it is showing `null`, change the condition to `if($metadata===null)` from `if($metadata)` and it will work correctly.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i do that, with same error. Plz refresh.

Comment: remove the `var_dump($metadata);exit;` i have seen the change, change the condition to `if($metadata===null)` from `if($metadata)`

Comment: i am talking about this condition in your layout file https://i.imgur.com/IQFPV2U.png

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam now by removing that command, site is on. But the meta tags are all the same, yet.

Comment: becuase there is a logical fault the way it is created it will always show the home page metadata for all the pages where it wont find the pattern or `page_routing` as `controller/action`, means for the  `site` and `exam`, you should first save the url for the home page as `site/index` instead of just `site` and `exam` as `exam/index` in the database from backend and then remove the condition altogether just use the output from the query.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam How can i contact with you directly? If you have time and my site passwords, can you correct this issue? Plz.

Comment: @muhammadomaraslam can you help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I'm still waiting for your help. In IRAN, i couldn't find any developer to fix this problem.